# libmps-iLog.a: could not read symbols: File in wrong format

Tags: c++, makefile

I compiled all the cpp files inside a folder called CplusplusObjects into libmps-cplusplus.a. When I tried using that libmps-cplusplus.a for making the shared object in another makefile, then I get libmps-cplusplus.a: could not read symbols: File in wrong format** error.

On searching for similar problems, I figure out that this problem is related with mixing of 32 bit and 64 bit versions but I have specifically mentioned 64 bit in both of these make files.

***makefile for CplusplusObjects***

```
#
# Makefile : C++Objects
#
# Explicit setting of SHELL
SHELL=/bin/sh
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79
WA_ROOT=/localdata/sunny/CDDmain/sw

# source files.
SRC = Aggregations.cpp BasicRouter.cpp cac.cpp CapacityRouting.cpp 

OBJS = $(SRC:%.cpp=%.o)

OUT = $(WA_ROOT)/build/lib/libmps-Cplusplus.a

# include directories
INCLUDES = -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include \
-I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/linux \
-I $(WA_ROOT)/mps/iLog/DiverseRoute -I $(WA_ROOT)/mps/iLog/jniBridge \
-I $(WA_ROOT)/mps/iLog/C++Objects -I $(WA_ROOT)/mps/iLog/Simulator

# C++ compiler flags (-g -O2 -Wall)
#CCFLAGS = -g
CCFLAGS = -m64 -DBIT64 -shared -fPIC -g -ansi -c

# compiler
CC = /usr/bin/g++


# System defined library paths and names
#SYSLIBS=-L../ -L/usr/local/lib -lm
SYSLIBS= 

# User defined library paths and names
LIBS = 

# compile flags
#LDFLAGS = -g
LDFLAGS =

AR = /usr/bin/ar -rvu

.SUFFIXES: .cpp

.cpp.o : 
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $*.cpp -o $*.o

all:$(OUT)
$(OUT) : $(OBJS)
    $(AR) $(OUT) $(OBJS)
    /usr/bin/ranlib $(OUT)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(OUT) Makefile.bak
```

makefile for jnibridge

```
#
# Makefile : jniBridge
#
# Explicit setting of SHELL
SHELL=/bin/sh
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79
WA_ROOT=/localdata/sunny/CDDmain/sw

# source files.
SRC = AutomatedDelayAnalysis.cpp AutomatedAnalysis.cpp /     DelayAnalysis.cpp  

OBJS = $(SRC:%.cpp=%.o)

OUT = $(WA_ROOT)/build/lib/libmpsAlgo.so

# include directories

INCLUDES = -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include \
-I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/linux \
-I $(WA_ROOT)/mps/iLog/DiverseRoute -I $(WA_ROOT)/mps/iLog/jniBridge \
-I $(WA_ROOT)/mps/iLog/C++Objects -I $(WA_ROOT)/mps/iLog/Simulator \
-I$(WA_ROOT)/3rdParty/csim/csim20_64bit/gpp/lib

# C++ compiler flags (-g -O2 -Wall)
#CCFLAGS = -g
CCFLAGS = -m64 -DBIT64 -ansi -c

# compiler
CC = /usr/bin/g++

# System defined library path and names
#SYSLIBS=-L../ -L/usr/local/lib -lm
SYSLIBS= 

# User defined library paths and names
LIBS = -L$(WA_ROOT)/build/lib -L$(WA_ROOT)/3rdParty/csim/csim20_64bit/gpp/lib \ -lmps-Cplusplus 

# compile flags
#LDFLAGS = -g
LDFLAGS = -m64 -DBIT64

.SUFFIXES: .cpp

.cpp.o : 
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $*.cpp -o $*.o

all:$(OUT)
$(OUT) : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $(OUT) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(LIBS) 

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(OUT) Makefile.bak
```

Here is the output of the final make file

```
-bash-4.1$ make -f makefile64bit
/usr/bin/g++ -o /localdata/sunny/CDDmain/sw/build/lib/libmpsAlgo.so -m64 
-DBIT64 AutomatedDelayAnalysis.o AutomatedAnalysis.o DelayAnalysis.o jniADMux.o TrayCanvas.o TrayHandler.o 
-L/localdata/sunny/CDDmain/sw/build/lib -    L/localdata/sunny/CDDmain/sw/3rdParty/csim/csim20_64bit/gpp/lib -lmps-Cplusplus
/localdata/sunny/CDDmain/sw/build/lib/libmps-Cplusplus.a: could not read symbols:
File in wrong format collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [/localdata/sunny/CDDmain/sw/build/lib/libmpsAlgo.so] Error 1
```

Comment: Can you show the make output from building both the `.a` and the `.so` files?

Comment: just added the output of the make file above.

Comment: That's not complaining about the file you built from the first makefile though. Where does `-lcsim.gpp` come from in that output? Are these actually the makefiles in use? What does `file /localdata/sunny/CDDmain/sw/build/lib/libmps-iLog.a` say? What about `nm /localdata/sunny/CDDmain/sw/build/lib/libmps-iLog.a`?

Comment: Sorry there was a mistake in the make output. I have corrected them.

Comment: And `file` and `nm` report what on that `.a` file?

Comment: libmps-Cplusplus.a is the output of the first make file. Second make file use this along with the .o files to create a final .so file.

Comment: That doesn't answer my questions at all. Run `file /localdata/sunny/CDDmain/sw/build/lib/libmps-Cplusplus.a` and `nm /localdata/sunny/CDDmain/sw/build/lib/libmps-Cplusplus.a` and show the output.

Comment: The result of file is 
-bash-4.1$ file libmps-Cplusplus.a
libmps-Cplusplus.a: current ar archive and the result of nm is quite long.

Comment: And the output of `objdump -af` on the file?

Comment: I am adding here a portion of the output since the output of objdump is also long.

STDCAlgo.o:     file format elf64-x86-64
rw-r--r-- 15158/30000 280376 Sep  1 09:34 2015 STDCAlgo.o
architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000011:
HAS_RELOC, HAS_SYMS
start address 0x0000000000000000


OsrpGroomingCapacityPlanning.o:     file format elf32-i386
rw-r--r-- 15158/30000 1572708 Aug 28 11:04 2015 OsrpGroomingCapacityPlanning.o
architecture: i386, flags 0x00000011:
HAS_RELOC, HAS_SYMS
start address 0x00000000

Comment: Update the post so you can format the output please. At least one of those entries appears to be a 32bit object file. What is `OsrpGroomingCapacityPlanning.o`? Is that one of your built files? Is that an older file from some other attempt?

Comment: Yes @EtanReisner, you are right. The problem is with the OsrpGroomingCapacityPlanning.o that is 32 bit object file. Now, I am wondering why this file gets compiled as 32 bit when other are compiled as 64 bit and in the option, I have specifically added -m64 for compilation.

Comment: `OsrpGroomingCapacityPlanning` isn't mentioned in your first makefile. Are you building it? Or is it already in the archive file and you are just updating on top of it?

Comment: Yah, I am updating on top of it.

Comment: Did removing and building the archive from scratch fix the problem then?

Comment: Yah. That actually fixed the problem. Thanks

Comment: You should explain that a bit more in your answer and then accept it then.

Comment: Sure @EtanReisner. I will do that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objdump -af libmps-Cplusplus.a libmps-Cplusplus.a as suggested by @EtanReisner indicated that one file called OsrpGroomingCapacityPlanning.o was there which is compiled as file format elf32-i386. This caused the "could not read symbols: File in wrong format** error". In order to correct this, I have to remove the OsrpGroomingCapacityPlanning.o from the archive and compile it manually and put it with other .o files and make an archive again.